# how do i load remote text from a text file into android textview?

Tags: android, file, text, load

I have gone through all the examples and I can not seem to get this to work.

This is my current code:

```
package hello.android;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloAndroidActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        try {
            // Create a URL for the desired page
            URL url = new URL("http://xlradioaustin.com/song/CurrentSong.txt");

            // Read all the text returned by the server
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String str;
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                // str is one line of text; readLine() strips the newline character(s)
            }
            in.close();
            tv.setText(str);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            tv.setText("mal");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            tv.setText("io");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your stacktrace? it is hard to offer solutions without knowing what the exact error is.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your Android device is online and you've granted your app the INTERNET permission, try this:

```
try {
            // Create a URL for the desired page
            URL url = new URL("http://xlradioaustin.com/song/CurrentSong.txt");

            // Read all the text returned by the server
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String str;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100);
            while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(str);
                // str is one line of text; readLine() strips the newline character(s)
            }
            in.close();
            tv.setText(sb.toString());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            tv.setText("mal");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            tv.setText("io");
        }
```

Let me know if that works: you are currently looping until `str` is null, then using that null value.

Comment: Yea, if you are new to permissions, check out this sample manifest: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/AndroidManifest.html

Comment: Ok, I went with a different bit and it seemed to work after i added in permissions , 

but how could i make it loop that and refresh the text file every 15-20 sec? this is for an online radio station and we have a text file that updates often with current playing track

Comment: You'll need to make sure you're running on the right thread, but otherwise it is pretty standard: package it into a method and trigger it with a timer.

Comment: Im such a beginner can you give an example of how to do that?

Comment: yeah, i think it would take me several hours to figure that out, just not sure how to do it. they need to make things more simple to read. like, here is a loop that goes every 15 seconds, inside place your code to do some action...

Comment: yeah, im just clueless... trying to wrap my head around this, but not happening

Comment: You can also look at http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/using-handler-in-android.html, but that is honestly one of the better guides you'll find.

Comment: well ive been spinning my wheels now for 20 mins, lets see, so far nadda

and funny, i was working on that same tut, but im getting error force close. i need more info such as main.xml or permissions, or whatever the heck. they dont tell you all the code you need. really freakn frustrating. i come from a php background and man they make it easy! guess I was spoiled by people that knew how to communicate.

Comment: here is an example

just trunk svn your souce code method class onject indetifier and inject some pepper and ajax a jink and jive. just like that? see how easy that was? I know that you reading my tut already know the lingo and not one of you is a new guy, so therefore i wont explain a single thing. as a matter of fact i wont even post a tut cause you already know

Comment: How to keep newline and enter?

Answer (score 1):

A follow up on the answer, it worked after adding

```
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
       StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
       StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
      }
```