# How to load a file .txt from the website to the android textview?

Tags: android, web

i just want to know how to load the **.txt** file from the website to our online connected android app.

i simply like to load the text in an online application using the internet to a text view, is there any best way to do that.

as i am very new to android so gone through many tutorial and questions on stack overflow but non worked for me.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902560/how-do-i-load-remote-text-from-a-text-file-into-android-textview

Answer (score 3):

You can use the volley library which is provided and advised by Google.
(Gradle dependency 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.10')
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yhv8l9F44qo

```
    String url = "your_txt_file_url";
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            //response is what you want :)
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            //Error occurred
        }
    });

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    queue.add(request);
```

Hope it help!

Comment: Would highly recommend this answer as it faster and easier to implement

Answer (score 2):

Embed this AsyncTask within the activity you want to display the text:

```
private class LoadTextFileTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private TextView txtView;

    public LoadTextFileTask(TextView txtView) {
        this.txtView = txtView;
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String url = urls[0];
        Log.d(TAG, "fetching: " + url);
        try {
            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
            if (con.getResponseCode() != 200)
                throw new IOException();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
                response.append(inputLine);
            in.close();
            return response.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "error downloading file", e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String text) {
        if (text != null) {
            txtView.setText(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Then execute this task when you want to load the text, given the file URL and the TextView reference:

```
new LoadTextFileTask(yourTextView).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, yourTextFileURL);
```

Comment: Good, although it seems unnecessary to use StringBuffer instead of StringBuilder, since any given instance of it is only being used by one thread.